# Full-resolution accelerometer / sensor data on mobile browsers in google chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, accelerometer, sensors

There appears to be what amounts to a bug (or very unhelpful feature) in mobile Chrome browser related to device motion.  When retrieving data in a mobile browser from the device sensors (eg accelerometer) using javascript in google chrome mobile, the data is rounded to only about two significant digits, making it nearly unusable for many purposes, though the raw device data is far more accurate than this.  No idea why.  I presume that the browser must be rounding it, perhaps out of security concerns?  The same code does not produce this behavior on mobile safari or on Samsung mobile internet browser.

How can you get the full-resolution sensor data?

Example code that produces rounded data:

```
window.addEventListener("devicemotion", handleMotionEvent, true);
handleMotionEvent: function(event) {
result = event.acceleration.x;
// do something with result.  Result datapoints will be, eg: 3.200000004, 3.4000000....
}
```

Using the api elements like this produces the same behavior:

```
accelerometer = new Accelerometer({ referenceFrame: 'device' });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In ["Quantize sensor values to protect user privacy"](https://crrev.com/497c54a8c62538b0c2506df96a79cbd67f5f983a) the exposed precision of sensor data was intentionally reduced.

This is "working as intended" unless use cases are identified that were affected other than attempting to identify a user.  A [chromium issue](https://crbug.com/1148241) was filed on this topic and is a good place to raise use cases if needed.